# aws: error: argument command for opensearchserverless

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to list open source serverless collections with the aws cli. I am on version 2.7 of the cli. The amazon docs seem to show that [opensearchserverless](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/opensearchserverless/index.html) is a valid cli command. But if I run

`aws opensearchserverless help` I get `aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are ...`

I am confused about why opensearchserverless is not considered a valid command.

If I run the following it shows that I am running version 2 of the CLI. Did they change this command within version 2? I am wary of reinstalling my aws command, although that might fix it.

`$ which aws`

`/usr/local/bin/aws`

`$ aws --version`

`aws-cli/2.7.21 Python/3.9.11 Darwin/21.6.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changelog indicates `opensearchserverless` was introduced in [2.9.3](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/aws-cli/v2/CHANGELOG.rst) version, so you'll need to update your version

```
2.9.3
=====
...
* api-change:opensearchserverless: Publish SDK for Amazon OpenSearch Serverless
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I did not know about the changelog so thanks.